# Recaptcha angularjs verify user's answer

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I am using the following plugin https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha in order to use recaptcha at a login form.

I am using the following code for verification

```
$http({
            url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify', 
            method: 'POST',
            params: {privatekey: "key", remoteip: "userip", challenge: "challenge", response: "user_answer" },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (valid) {
                console.log('Success');
                alert('Success');

            } else {
                console.log('Failed validation');
                alert('Fail');

                // In case of a failed validation you need to reload the captcha because each challenge can be checked just once
                //vcRecaptchaService.reload();
            }

        });
```

But google server is not returning anything.
I updated the code but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code:

```
post: 'GET'
```

Change that to `method: 'GET'` or `method: 'POST'`.
You can check out [angular documentation on http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) to make sure you've written all the params right.

If this wasn't the source of your problems, you should post more details about your issue (what do you see in your networkl console for example).

Comment: Request Headers
Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host www.google.com
Origin http://mydomain.com
Referer http://mydomain.com/myapp/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that recaptcha validation must be done at server-side. I'm not 100% sure that you are doing that in the browser, but your code looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel Trias stated, you shall not validate directly from angularjs/javascript client, instead you should send the challenge and response field to your server and validate then.

Therefore you can use the uri you used (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify) or a plugin, e.g. if you use php see https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php. I'd prefer a plugin because it will save work.

Furthermore keep in mind that your private key should not be used in the client, this is why it is called private. It is only used to communicate between your server and the reCaptcha servers. The public key is used to communicate between your client and the reCaptcha servers.
For more info read the [Overview](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)